# Prove that $\exists_{x_0}f''(x_0)=0$

Tags: derivatives

$f \in C[0;2]$, $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 2$. $f''$ exists on $(0;2)$. Prove that $\exists_{x_0 \in (0;2)}f''(x_0)=0$. Mayme it's possible to use Rolle's theorem, but I don't see how to apply it in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: Apply Rolle's Theorem to g(x) = f(x) - x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply two times the Rolle theorem to $g(x)=f(x)- x$ in  $[0,1]\;, [1,2]$  ,and you have  in $x_0,x_1 \in (0,2)$ that $g'(x_0)=g'(x_1)=0$ and again use the rolle theorem

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the MVT to see $f'= 1$ at two different points.

Comment: But $f(x) = x$ satisfies the conditions of the question without having that conclusion.

Comment: @zhw:  Maybe you mean $f'$ is $1$ at two different points.

Comment: Thank you @T.Bongers and AndréNicolas, will edit.